# Questions about casting

Tags: java, casting, gson

I am trying to make a game with auth system in Java. When I am trying to run it, i can see an exception thrown in the console log but there is no error in the project. I know this is runtime error

The console log displays the following information:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to Auth$Profile
    at Auth.<init>(Auth.java:30)
```

Here is my code:

```
 public Auth(File profilesFile) {
              try {
                  ProfilesJSON e = (ProfilesJSON)this.gson.fromJson(new FileReader(profilesFile), ProfilesJSON.class);
                 Map ps = e.authenticationDatabase;
                 Iterator var5 = ps.keySet().iterator();

                 while(var5.hasNext()) {
                    String name = (String)var5.next();
                    Profile p = (Profile)ps.get(name);
                    if(p != null) {
                       if(p.displayName == null || p.displayName.length() == 0) {
                          p.displayName = p.username;
                       }

                       this.profiles.add(p);
                    }
                 }

              } catch (FileNotFoundException var7) {
                 ;
              } catch (NullPointerException var8) {
                 ;
              }
           }


    public class Profile {

              public String username;
              public String password;
              public String uid;
              public String displayName;
              public String name;
              public String playerUID;


              public Profile(String u, String t, String id, String d) {
                 this.username = u;
                 this.password = t;
                 this.uid = id;
                 this.displayName = d;
              }
           }

public class ProfilesJSON {

          public Map profiles;
          public String selectedProfile;
          public String password;
          public Map authenticationDatabase;


       }
```

Line 30 is:

```
Profile p = (Profile)ps.get(name);
```

This is a part of my code, my idea is if the player press "Remember Password", the game will generate a .json file to store his infomation..I just want to know what I did wrong, other code i can write it myself

Comment: *ClassCastException* Java tried to perform a cast but cannot due to no inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Your `ps.get(name)` is returning a `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` object instead of `Profile`.

try to change it to:

```
LinkedTreeMap p = (LinkedTreeMap )ps.get(name);
```

Your code doesn't show you errors because there's no error in compile time, [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)  is a runtime exception.

Comment: No... this class never use com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap and if i change my code to yours, I get project error => p.displayName cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @user2718549 There is certainly a `LinkedTreeMap` object present, and it came from somewhere. Find out. The compile error you mention is caused by another change, not this one. Surely that's obvious?

Comment: I don't see how. I don't know what's being put into your Profile object for a start. Only you know that.

Comment: @user2718549 you should check where that LinkedTreeMap object comes from, obviously it comes from e.authenticationDatabase, check when it's loaded and why does it have a LinkedTreeMap object inside.

Comment: @AminAbu-Taleb I search all the class in this project, I can't found any class use com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap. My classes only use com.google.gson.Gson

Comment: @user2718549 use your debug to check the content of your map and verify the Object type and where it comes from

Comment: @AminAbu-Taleb I found it! The debug said "Name : ps   Value : LinkedMapTree<K, V> id=40"

Comment: @user2718549 nice, now you have to find out where it comes from xD

Comment: @AminAbu-Taleb It came from  Map ps = e.authenticationDatabase;

Comment: @AminAbu-Taleb so how to fix it? And.... this class didn't import the class "com.google.gson.interal.LinkedMapTree"